# XLS to CSV escaping

Tags: xml, excel, csv

How would you escape properly the delimiter char from actual content when exporting an `XLS` to `CSV`?.

When I export a file, the delimiter is `";"` character which is also found in some fields. I need to escape it

Comment: Well, `;` is not CSV, but if it otherwise follows the CSV rules, just put quotes around your values, as in `"Here is my; value"`  If your export routine is not doing that for you already, it's probably not CSV compliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually no completely accepted standard for the CSV "format".

Standard practice, however, is:

1. Enclose any field values with a "special character" in double-quotes.
2. For any field values that are enclosed in double-quotes, escape any internal double-quote characters in the field by repeating the double-quote character.

So, ID = 10, Name = Doe; John, Nickname = Johnny "The Chin" would look like this:

```
10; "Doe; John"; "Johnny ""The Chin"""
```

if you're using semi-colons (commas are more common, hence the name Comma Separated Values).

Special characters that require the quoting are the delimiter (whatever it is), the double-quote character itself, and line breaks (if both the sending and receiving programs support line breaks within a field).  However, if both the sending and receiving programs support the use of double-quotes around field values, it doesn't hurt to include them for all fields.